# How to make mobs upside down while riding a bat

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am wondering if you can make riding mobs of a bat upside down, I saw a video where a mob was upside down and wanted a code to make it. I want the bat to be invisible and invulnerable and another command to not be invisible, but still invulnerable. (2 commands)

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 3):

Invisible Bat:

```
/summon Creeper ~ ~2 ~ {Riding:{id:"Bat",Invulnerable:1b,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Duration:9999999}]},CustomName:"Dinnerbone"}
```

Not Invisible Bat:

```
/summon Creeper ~ ~2 ~ {Riding:{id:"Bat",Invulnerable:1b},CustomName:"Dinnerbone"}
```

Of course, the coordinates can be changed to your liking.